# how to display textarea without scrollbar using jsf?

Tags: jsf-2

I want inputTextarea auto growing when being typed.But I don't want scrollbar. I have done **overflow: hidden** ,it's not showing scroll but it's also not auto growing.

```
<h:inputTextarea id="ta1" cols="25" style="overflow: hidden"/>
```

please give me reply.

Comment: Hi, Which JSF components suite you are using ? If you are using Primefaces you have <p:inputTextarea rows="6" cols="33" /> which has auto growing.

Answer (score 2):

The auto growing textarea is **not** a standard feature of the HTML `<textarea>` element as generated by the JSF `<h:inputTextarea>`. This is usually been achieved by adding some shot of JavaScript code. Here's a basic kickoff example.

```
<h:inputTextarea ... onkeyup="autoGrow(this)" />
```

with

```
function autoGrow(textarea) {
    if (textarea.clientHeight < textarea.scrollHeight) {
        textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
```