# h:inputTextarea with dynamic size

Tags: jsf

I'm using an `<h:inputTextarea>` to display some text. Is there a way to change the rows to adjust the size of the text?

```
<h:inputTextarea rows="2"
                 cols="100"
                 readonly="true"
                 style="width:400px; border-style:none; background: transparent;"
                 onkeypress="limitTextArea(this, 'txtObsDoc', 4000);"
                 onkeyup="limitTextArea(this, 'txtObsDoc', 4000);"
                 onblur="limitTextArea(this, 'txtObsDoc', 4000);"
                 value="#{content}"
                 rendered="#{applicationBean.configuracaoDocflow.habilitarTextArea}">
</h:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that an `<h:inputTextarea>` should expand or shrink automatically as the number of rows in the `<h:inputTextarea>` increases or decreases respectively as some text is entered into or removed from?

Comment: yes something like that, right now we are using it just as an output, but the size of the text can be anything from a phrase to a huge text. The text will come from the bean already setted and it'll not change after it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display textarea without scrollbar using jsf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008696/how-to-display-textarea-without-scrollbar-using-jsf)